# Changing alpha of Sprite

Tags: unity

I'm using OnGUI to draw a rect when I "box select" or "drag select". The texture that gets drawn is a PNG file made in Paint.Net with the opacity - alpha channel set quite low. In Unity however, when I go to box select, the texture is completely opaque. How do I get Unity to honor the alpha set in Paint.Net? I also wouldn't mind using Unity itself to adjust the opacity, but I haven't found such an option in the import texture part of the inspector.

Comment: By the way: `OnGUI` is deprecated. You should use [the new UI system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, avoid at all costs OnGUI except for debug purpose. Use the [Unity GUI system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html).

In your favorite image software (Paint.Net), **set the opacity of your image to 1** and import your image into Unity. Now, take a closer look to the following screenshot representing the Import Settings of an image and do the same to your own image :

[image: Import Settings]

The main things to notice are :

- **Texture type** : Sprite (2D and UI)
- **Alpha source** : Input Texture Alpha
- **Alpha is Transparency** : checked

Then, in your scene, add a new `Canvas` and add an `Image` as a child. Select the `Image` gameobject and set your image as a sprite of your image. Finally, you will be able to manage the opacity using the `Alpha` channel of the sprite color.

[image]

*Note : To create a canvas and the child image :*

1. *GameObject menu > UI > Canvas*
2. *Select the canvas in the Hierarchy*
3. *GameObject menu > UI > Image (or right click on your canvas : UI > Image)*